# AJAX Table refresh with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html-table

I want to refresh a table, filled with JSON data, for example every 5 Seconds.

The table should be refreshed without a complete site refresh. New items should be added, lost items should be deleted. How do I refresh it now with AJAX?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<table face="comic sans ms" border="1" id="usertable"></table>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
            $.each(cars, function(key, data){
                console.log(data.carName);
                var vint=data.vin;
                var coopers="";
                var tanken="";
                var drive="MAN";
                var fuelfarbe="#01DF3A";
                var prozent="%";
                var v=vint.substring(3,7);
                if(v=="SX31"){coopers=" S";}
                if(v=="SW71"){coopers=" SD";}
                if(data.auto=="Y"){drive="AUT";}
                if(data.fuelState<=25){tanken="20 Freiminuten für Vollbetankung"; fuelfarbe="#FF4000";}
                $('#usertable').append(
                    function() {
                        return "<tr>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.carName+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.model+coopers+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+drive+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.fuelState+prozent+"</td>"+
                                    //"<td>"+data.address+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data.licensePlate+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+tanken+"</td>"
                                "<tr>"; 
                    }
                );
            })
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Comment: I would highly recommend you look into using something like Knockout for something like this.  Otherwise, you'll pull your hair out when it comes time to make changes.   http://knockoutjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the `getJSON` in a function

```
function dummy()
{
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON(
        "url",
        function(json){ });
    });
}
```

and

give

```
setInterval( dummy, 5000 );
```

Comment: ok i tried it now. Problem now: the table contents are added to the extisting table ... whats wrong?`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
//..//
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
function callJSON() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.getJSON('./url.php', function(data) {
            var cars = data.rec.vehicles.vehicles;
            $.each(cars, function(key, data){
//..//
                    }
                );
            })
        }).always(callJSON);
 }, 5000);
 }
 $(callJSON);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Sry :) .. iam a bloody beginner ... whats have to be changed on my above mentioned code? Thanks :)

Comment: simple on each ajax request you empty the table using `empty` and then populate it with new data.

Comment: So i put the empty() before the Call? `        }).always(callJSON);
 }, 5000);
 }
 empty(usertable);
 $(callJSON);`

Comment: i added usertable.empty(); but it sais that this is not a function

Comment: where do i get the id of my table? :)

Comment: Oh dude , do it like this `<table id="mytable">` use this id into jquery